# How do I configure indentation in vim in a specific way?

Tags: c++, vim, indentation

If I type the following

```
void main(int blah,
```

and then press enter, I want to continue here:

```
          float blah);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
:set cino=(0
```

For more about cinoption see [here.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html)

Answer (score 1):

The following commands will indent your code the right amount, using spaces rather than tabs and automatically indent after you start. The commands can be added to your .vimrc file.

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent
set smartindent
```

Source: http://drupal.org/node/29325

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you also read up on the smartindent and autoindent settings.

Comment: smartindent is obsolete.  It's best to pretend it doesn't exist.  The general indentation settings that should be in your ~/.vimrc are "set autoindent" and "filetype indent on".  The former is so you have a basic "return to the level of the previous line" behavior when there is no filetype-specific indentation.  The latter is to enable use of filetype-specific indentation.